# Invoking REST web service in IBM Integration Bus

Tags: web-services, rest, ibm-integration-bus

I am here with a query of how to invoke a REST web service using a message flow in IBM's Integration bus.

My requirement is as follows:

Firstly I have a SOAP web service which I expose. This SOAP web service when gets invoked I want to call another web service which is a REST web service.
I developed two message flows.

1. The first one (a sample dummy message flow) in which I have a SOAP Input node, a Java Compute node and a SOAP Reply node. In this scenario, when I try  to this SOAP web service and pass some Input then I get the same Input which I hope is an expected behavior.
2. Now the second flow is with a SOAP Input node, a HTTP Request node (for invoking a REST web service) and finally a SOAP Reply node. (3 nodes again in this flow).

I wanted to know if I am correctly implementing the second message flow here. If not, what else I need to add to this message flow so that my thing gets done nicely. If need to add some SOAP extract/envelope node to this flow.

The EXCEPTION I get whilst I try to invoke my SOAP web service is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: BIP3113E: Exception detected in message flow SingleArgMsgFlow.SOAP Input (broker IB9NODE) 
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:190)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:120)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:90)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:141)
  at $Proxy27.processRqst(Unknown Source)
  at org.tempuri.singleargmsgset.SingleArgInvoker.main(SingleArgInvoker.java:15)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!! :)

Comment: We will need to see your current code and also if it is not currently working, what errors you are receiving.

Comment: Hey friend, I updated my question with the exception I am getting while invoking my SOAP Message flow. @Stewartside